# How to distinguish Windows driver from dll

Tags: windows, dll, driver, init, dumpbin

I need to differ two binary files - a driver and a common dll. As far as I understand I need to view sections of this files (e.g. via DumpBin) and see if there is an INIT section. Is this criteria complete?

Comment: Just look at the IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SubSystem field.  Dumpbin.exe /headers displays it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the binary and look into Subsystem filed of IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER, if it's NATIVE, then it's a driver. Look into the following link for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx

Comment: Not entirely true. It could be a native program or DLL or a kernel mode DLL as well. "Native" actually means nothing other than "*no* subsystem". It's not some magic subsystem living somewhere on each Windows machine :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use heuristics to establish this fact and be certain to the extent possible. The problem is that there literally exist native user-mode programs (e.g. `autochk.exe`) and DLLs (frankly nothing comes to mind off hand, but I've seen them as part of native programs that do stuff before `winlogon.exe` gets to run) as well as kernel-mode counterparts (`bootvid.dll`, `hal.dll` and the kernel in one of its various forms `ntoskrnl.exe`).

So to establish it is a driver you could try the following:

1. `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER::SubSystem`, as pointed out, should signify that it's "native" (i.e. has no subsystem: `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_NATIVE`)
2. Verify that the `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER::Characteristics` is *not* DLL (which would mean it's a kernel or user mode DLL, check against `IMAGE_FILE_DLL`)
3. Make sure it does or does *not* import `ntdll.dll` or another user mode DLL or to the contrary that it imports one of the kernel mode modules (`ntoskrnl.exe`, `hal.dll`, `bootvid.dll`) to establish whether it would run in kernel or user mode.

The structs and defines are all included in `winnt.h`.

The gist:

- establish the subsystem (only `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_NATIVE` is interesting for your case)
- establish it is a DLL or not
- establish whether it links against user or kernel mode components